# Autogrowing UITextView inside UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static UItableView and one of its cell contains a text view and it want to make the text view autogrowable, and make the cell grow at the same time. Always wrapping text instead of cutting it.

In a isoalted Text View I dont face this issue due to I have fixed size and to show long texts I just have scroll inside the textview, but in this case I doesnt want scroll, for that my UITextView is set as nonScrolable because the parent (UITableView) already have scroll and I want to avoid nested scrolls.

My approach to sort this out is overrayde height.... and reload my view every time the user types using sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) to know the requerid size, and then set the UITextView cell size, and show the text correctly.

But the cell only grows a bit, and not enough, I researched about sizeThatFits to know if is as I understand it, a method to get the mesure of a object to fit inside another objets, or there is other parameters to care about like paddings, margins, or constriant and I'm not able to find where those things are explained.

Then I have this questions,
        did I missunderstood this method? how shoud I use it?
        Am I in the correct path to reach my goal? or there is a better way to do it?

Thank you so much.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let defaulHeight: CGFloat = 44

    if indexPath.row == textFieldRowNumber {
        let cellSize = messageTableViewCell.bounds.size
        let wantedSize = longMessageTextField.sizeThatFits(cellSize)
            return wantedSize.height
    } else {
        return defaulHeight
    }
}


func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange  range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    let previousMessageInput = longMessageTextField.text
    longMessageTextField.text = previousMessageInput! + text

    let indexToReload = NSIndexPath(forItem: 4, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexToReload], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)        
    return true
}
```